# How to read and write pickled information

Tags: python, list, pickle

I am a beginner in Python and have been attempting to write usernames and passwords to files from lists using a loop and `pickle`.

However, I am receiving the error:

```
NameError: name 'listusername' is not defined
```

for the following line of code:
`listusername.write("%s\n" % i)`

Here is the rest of my code:

```
userName = input('Please enter a username:\n')
password1 = input('Please enter a password:\n')
user_names=[]
passwords=[]
user_names.append(userName)
passwords.append(password1)
for i in user_names:
    listusername.write("%s\n" % i)

for i in user_names:
    listusername.read("%s\n" % i)

for i in passwords:
    listpassword.write("%s\n" % i)

for i in passwords:
    listpassword.read("%s\n" % i)
```

All answers and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Which file should the usernames/passwords be written to? How does `python` get to know that?

Comment: What is `listusername`?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking about here. The error is absolutely clear; you have not defined "listusername". What is confusing you about that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman   I'm wondering how to define 'listusername'

Comment: You are not pickling anything.

Comment: You have not even opened the files that you call them `listusername` and `listpassword`, there is no call to the function `open()`

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)? If not, why not? If yes, which part of it remains unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your code that you expect `listusername` to be a file object that lets you write strings and then read, uh, something. I don't understand `listusername.read("%s\n" % i)` and I suspect that neither do you.

Look, I get it. You're confused. You're a novice programmer. Let me help you out.

If you run this Python script, it will ask you for some account information, pickle it, and write it to a file named `accounts.pickled`.

```
import pickle

accounts = []

# Let's collect some account information.
username = input('Please enter a username: ')
password = input('Please enter a password: ')
account = (username, password)    # This tuple represents an account.
accounts.append(account)          # Add it to the list of accounts.

# Write the pickled accounts to a file.
with open('accounts.pickled', 'wb') as out_file:
  pickle.dump(accounts, out_file)
```

Notice that we're writing out an array called `accounts` that only contains a single account. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to collect information about several accounts.

Later, when you want to read the accounts from the file, you can run the following script.

```
import pickle

# Unpickle the accounts.
with open('accounts.pickled', 'rb') as in_file:
  accounts = pickle.load(in_file)

# Display the accounts one at a time.
for account in accounts:
  username, password = account
  print('username: %s, password: %s' % (username, password))
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me understand what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

In your code here

```
for i in user_names:
    listusername.write("%s\n" % i)
```

Python has no idea what listusername is. This is why it is erroring with

> NameError: name 'listusername' is not defined

To fix the issue, you could set listusername first before using it, e.g.

```
listusername = open('output.txt', 'w')
for i in user_names:
    listusername.write("%s\n" % i)
```

However, this step is totally unnecessary - as your question deals with the pickle module - where the documentation comes with an [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example). Here's a solution to your problem:

```
userName = input('Please enter a username:\n')
password1 = input('Please enter a password:\n')
user_names=[]
passwords=[]
user_names.append(userName)
passwords.append(password1)

import pickle
with open('user_names.txt', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(f, user_names)
with open('passwords.txt', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump(f, passwords)
```